# My package is not importing showing No such module 'MoEngageSDK'

Tags: swift, xcode, import, sdk, moengage

I have tried many solutions like disintegrating pods, cleaning, rebuild, but my issue didn't solve. I'm stuck on this for 2 days and didn't get any proper solution.

The package is showing as xcframework not the framework in the pods.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

are you using the M1 chip Mac? if yes then You have to add arm64 in **Build Settings -> Build Architecture** and in pods **Build Settings -> Build Architecture** as well.